# Why does the restoration of the metadata and the saved model fail?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have defined a deep learning model using the Lenet5 architecture.
I saved the result and the metadata.
I tried to reuse them to predict on the new images.
But even though the model yielded a validation accuracy of 97.7%, a test accuracy of 95.8%, the prediction on new images gives an accuracy of 0%.

It seems that the problem occurs due to incorrect restoration of the model.
It seems that the tensors are not found properly.
Then I named the tensors to solve the problem.
Finally, I am stuck with a naming problem.

Here is the code: < [click me](https://github.com/chatmoon/Debugging/blob/master/_171109_1434_TSC-Debugging.py) >
And the data are available here: < [click me](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset) >

The traces:

```
Training... model: model1, rate: 0.00085, epochs: 2, batch size: 100, keep_prob: 0.67

Epoch:   0 | cost : 0.631 | Val.accu : 0.816
Epoch:   1 | cost : 0.419 | Val.accu : 0.900
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./logs/nn_logs/171113x1008/model1.ckpt
Validation Accuracy = 0.900
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./logs/nn_logs/171113x1008/model1.ckpt
Test Accuracy = 0.880
< myLabel > = [0, 1, 2, 32, 35]
< repo name of the model > : 171113x1008
```

And I get the following erro message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-e08ed0fc9454>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/mo/_171109_1434_TSC-Debugging.py', wdir='C:/Users/mo/_Coding_')

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/mo/_171109_1434_TSC-Debugging.py", line 910, in <module>
    myPredictionGRAY, ch = fctPrediction(myImg2, pathCkp)

  File "C:/Users/mo/_171109_1434_TSC-Debugging.py", line 889, in fctPrediction
    metaModel = tf.train.import_meta_graph(Ckp+ckptMeta)

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1595, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\meta_graph.py", line 499, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 308, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2339, in create_op
    self._add_op(ret)

  File "C:\Users\mo\Anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2033, in _add_op
    "is already used" % op.name)
```

The error message:
    **ValueError: cannot add op with name layer1/layer1W/optAdam as that name is already used**

Thank for your support,
mo

Comment: If you've already re-defined the `Graph` using Python code, maybe you just want to create a new `tf.train.Saver()` and use `restore` to load the checkpoint? Rather than defining the `Graph` once with Python code and then trying to re-define it by importing the `MetaGraph`.

Comment: @AllenLavoie, thx for your feedback. Well appreciated. If I well understood, I should not redefine the graph. Then I should remove "graph = tf.Graph()" and restore the checkpoint. I will try that and keep you posted. Thx.